# Too late now due to being fired, but advice for future appreciated

Tags: job-change

I am curious to hear different people's take on poor performance.

The first few reviews went well and then after 10 months was an email, followed by review/meeting. I don't recall many negative experiences in that time period, but worked occasional weekend, stayed late, etc.

The email was critical of me, listing numerous failings and problems. It came as a bit of a shock. The email had probably 10-15 bullet points noting missteps, etc., very few of which were brought up with me personally before.

So, it felt like a personal attack. At this point I can see how it would be a matter of time before falling into that situation, and I can also see how there is no way out once it has happened. It was not a "come see me," but more of an external "what are you doing to fix all of these problems?"

I read it, panicked, waited a few days, then talked to my boss, and was probably told I waited too long, etc., had the email re-iterated to me, and then was asked to check in more. I should have "checked in" more and gave more indication of desire to "improve," even if you think you've learned the skills and are not being challenged / not interested.

Starting out I showed urgency and made sure to learn and do things accurately and quickly, and tell people when I'm finished, high marks, very good attendance. The carrot and the stick a major driver here - new hires get praise so they'll stay on, the longer you've been the more seniority you have.

I could have taken steps sooner to "correct" things within my power. When I would ask for feedback or verify I was doing what needed to be done it was usually disregarded.

In response to lack of questions:

Ways to determine good fit?
How do you justify taking a break outside when you need a break?
Is office work basically awful?
Advice for those who can't deal?
Is it all about communicating your needs?

I don't know, looking for ways people stuck out jobs for one reason or another, whether or not they liked it.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here. Asking for experiences doesn't work with this format. Can you try to turn this into a concrete question that you want answers for?

Comment: "Also written up for taking a quick nap"  work is for work home is for napping.

Comment: VTC. This is not a forum and I'm not seeing a question.

Answer (score 2):

This may sound harsh, but here goes.

From what we have, it reads like you started well in the job, got through the probationary period and got some good praise.

Then it seems like you stopped working hard and produced less output.

Your employer then sent you a list of things you needed to work on, and then you didn't work on them enough to avoid the sack.

Ask yourself the following questions:

1. Did you enjoy the job?
2. Did you like your colleagues?
3. Did your quality of work drop off from what sounds like a good start?
4. Once you received the email, did you improve on the points in the email?

I understand if you are in a role/company you don't like, it can lead to demotivation and this will have perfomance issues. I've been there before, so know what it's like.

The fact you worked late/weekends is irrelevant. It could mean that you weren't productive enough in the office to get your weeks worth of tasks done in the work hours, so had to work more hours to get it done.

Also, napping at work whilst your performance is being monitored is a terrible idea, and i'm not sure what you expected to happen.

From the question, it sounded like the points on the email were valid. As you didn't seemingly challenge any of the points.

You don't really make it clear what steps you took to improve your performance. It seems like you took the email as a stepproving your sacking is inevitable.

In your meeting with your boss, you should have outlined measurable outputs to prove your performance is improving. That way you know their expectations and what you need to do to prove to your boss you are a valued member of staff.

It sounds like to me that you didn't perform well enough in your job to keep it. You need to look at yourself and determine whether it was the environment that was the reason, or is it the industry, your career choice or something else (possibly even outside of work) that caused you to become disinterested in working.

Comment: Thanks for giving feedback. Wasn't in love with it but tried to keep a good appearance, then felt the loss of motivation. I feel I was completing tasks too quickly early on instead of "managing" tasks and just taking my time, which creates boredom. Weekend work wasn't unusual for others, and never went without recognition, along with extra-work activities. It would be seen as "stepping up."

Comment: So later on why weren't you completing tasks quickly? You started off working hard then stopped working hard and wonder why your ex employer didn't like that?

Comment: To be honest maybe I should have taken things slowly; creating a tolerance for high competence isn't good and people expect more. Any thoughts on this and just being more balanced when you're working?

Comment: @user63090, high performance is expected everywhere. People with average performance may be kept on until there is a  layoff, but then they are the second groups to go (after the incompetents who haven;t managed to be fired yet). If you want to be lazy at work, then you need to be independently wealthy. Starting out as low/average performer is a way to get fired faster. What you need to do is to perform well at all times whether you feel motivated or not.

Comment: I still think I am missing something. Why can't you work quickly and consistently? Creating a tolerance for high competence IS what people want. If you are deemed highly competent then you will do well. Also, when you are highly competent, if something takes longer than expected, you can communicate that and people will trust you with that. If there's weekend work required, surely completing tasks quickly would mean you didn't need to work weekends.